# How to set a loading symbol at waiting time of download a file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have two jsp pages: One.jsp and Second.jsp

When i give download action, it is pointing to jsp page directly and there is no event. At a time of waiting to download, I want to set an image. I did this by ID, but after download completes, loading image doesn't disappear. How to hide it when download completes?

Here is my code:

```
document.getElementById("loading").style.visibility = "visible";

document.first.action="Second.jsp";
document.first.submit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ajax request on your page.

code for showing loader

```
<div class="loading-indicator">
    <img src='~/Images/loading2.gif' />
</div>
 $(document).ajaxSend(function (event, request, settings) {
        $('.loading-indicator').show();
    });

    $(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {
        $('.loading-indicator').hide();
    });
```

code for calling another jsp page

```
function ClickMe_Click(){
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "dimensionList.jsp",
    data: {"dimensionName":"Slappy"},
    success: function(msg) {
        alert(msg.data);
    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
    }  
});
return false;}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using ajax you can do this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).ajaxSend(function (event, request, settings) {
        $('.loading-indicator').show();
    });

    $(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {
        $('.loading-indicator').hide();
    });
});
```

code for showing loader

```
<div class="loading-indicator">
    <img src='~/Images/loading2.gif' />
</div>
```

loader will apper when ever the ajax call is made and hide when the ajax is call is completed